# How to Include/Exclude array of IDs from a relationship/pivot table and avoid duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Let's say you have

- `records` table with `id` and `name`
- `tags` table with `id` and `name`
- `records_tags` with `record_id` and `tags_id` (relationship table)

Now you want to run a query to include records that have X tags and exclude records that have X tags.

You could do `INNER JOIN`, but the **challenge here** is, when there are many tags to a record, it **creates duplicates** within the results.

Example:

```
inner join `records_tags` on `records_tags`.`record_id` = `records`.`id` 
and `records_tags`.`tag_id` in (?) and `records_tags`.`tag_id` not in (?)
```

As for the Laravel side, Ive used:

```php
$records->join('records_tags', function ($join) use($include, $exclude) {
   $join->on('records_tags.record_id','=','records.id');
   if ($include) $join->whereIn('records_tags.tag_id',$include);
   if ($exclude) $join->whereNotIn('records_tags.tag_id',$exclude);
});
```

Could there be a better solution to handle this or a way to ask for it to create unique or distinct rows, the goal of the join is only to include or exclude the actual records themselves from the results?

**Edit:**

The only other thing I can think of is doing something like this, still have to run tests to see accuracy, but for a crude solution

Edit 2: This doesn't appear to work on NOT IN as it creates duplicates.

```php
$records->join(\DB::raw('(SELECT tag_id, record_id FROM records_tags WHERE records_tags.tag_id IN ('.implode(',',$include).'))'),'records_tags.record_id','=','records.id');
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions in the `ON` clause:

```
... and `records_tags`.`tag_id` in (?) and `records_tags`.`tag_id` not in (?)
```

do not exclude from the results the ids of the records that you want to exclude.
Any `id` that is linked to any of the *wanted* tags will be returned even if it is also linked to an *unwanted* tag, because the joins return 1 row for each of the linked tags.

What you can use is aggregation and the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name
FROM records r INNER JOIN records_tags rt 
ON rt.record_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.id -- I assume that id is the primary key of records
HAVING SUM(rt.tag_id IN (?)) > 0
   AND SUM(rt.tag_id IN (?)) = 0;
```

or, if you want the ids that are linked to all the *wanted* tags, use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name
FROM records r INNER JOIN records_tags rt 
ON rt.record_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.id 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(rt.tag_id ORDER BY rt.tag_id) = ?;
```

In this case you will have to provide for the *wanted* tags `?` placeholder a sorted comma separated list of ids.

Comment: Thanks, im going to test out your other ideas with using `having` but I think the problem here is the setup wont allow me to use `GROUP BY r.id` because of `GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column` as there are many other columns being used, and multiple other joins which are 1-to-1, my example only provided a simple explanation.

Comment: @tmarois if `id` is the primary key of the table records then you can group by id only. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=959de79b7ffa99c437018b7d4f649a5d If not then you will have to include `name` in the group by clause.

Comment: yeah you're right it would work for the examples you provided, but on a more complex query, here is where my challenge is, since I'm including many 1-to-1 relationship tables, the only issue I have is with this one, which I cant seem to have it group unique https://pastebin.com/ePQTn4hq

Comment: @tmarois the code in the link does not contain any lists to include and/or exclude, so it does not have anything to do with the requirement as you present it in your question. Maybe you oversimplified. My code would work with any number of joins, as long as the returned columns exist in the main starting table (records).

Comment: Right, I did oversimplify, The query I pasted is a working query without the actual include/exclude functionality, it is still the same, trying to solve how to add that join on this existing query, for what you provided, I cant do the group by because MySQL error, unless its as easy as disabling the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` ?

Comment: Do you think there's anyway to accomplish this without the group by? or getting around this MySQL error? Its like I'm so close, but because of this limitation, it prevents me from doing it.

Comment: The only way I think I can do this is running a count on select and then using `having` to to use logic like you've provided, >0 or =0 for either include or exclude example select to add into the select `(select count(*) from tags inner join records_tags on tags.id = records_tags.tag_id where records.id = records_tags.record_id and (records_tags.tag_id IN (".implode(',',$exclude)."))) as exclude_count`